# Javascript or Rails : How to grab a BLE device or bluetooth

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm building a ruby on rails app and in which one of the requirement is to show all BLE devices within the range and show it on the HTML page.

I'm trying different possible ways but I couldn't find a right solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created an MQTT topic to grab the Bluetooth device and send it through node-red

Answer (score 1):

Rails isn't the right solution. It sounds like you are working on a progressive web app or something that will use some of the function of the device hardware where the code is running. This may or may not get you going in the right direction:
[Link](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/interact-with-ble-devices-on-the-web)